Trying to implement bootstrap carousel with flask application
I'm trying to implement a carousel widget in my Flask application.
Application is a fork of this project: https://github.com/MaxHalford/flask-boilerplate
I can see where the problem is: "next" and "previous" links on the slider are rendered to:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/about#carouselExampleIndicators

...whereas all internal links should render to a path as defined in main.py.
I just don't understand enough about how it's all put together t be able to crack this one on my own.
Any help, would be good.
Here's my code:
<!--carousel_test.html-->

{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>First Slide</h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/01.jpg') }}">
          <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Second Slide</h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/02.jpg') }}">
          <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Third Slide</h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/03.jpg') }}">
          <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/carousel.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}

I've tried to find a working example of carousel in flask, but haven't hit a close enough match.
I suspect my code being inside {% block content %} has something to do with it.
I've also done a plain HTML version to verify the .js and .css are valid and the code actually works outside of the Flask framework.
